# Minecraft: Multiple messages being sent

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm developing a plugin to prevent players from mining ores unless they have a permission. However i'm running into an issue where users are using another plugin alongside mine where it allows for them to mine 9 blocks at once. Well this spams the player with "You do not have permissions to mine this!" Can someone advise me a workaround for the messaging system? (Basically not spam the player).

```
        switch (type) {
    case COAL_ORE: {
        if (!player.hasPermission("PluginName.coal") && (!player.isOp())) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            player.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You do not have permission to mine Coal Ore!");
        }
        break;
    }
    case IRON_ORE: {
        if (!player.hasPermission("PluginName.iron") && (!player.isOp())) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            player.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You do not have permission to mine Iron Ore!");
        }
        break;
    }
    case GOLD_ORE: {
        if (!player.hasPermission("PluginName.gold") && (!player.isOp())) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            player.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You do not have permission to mine Gold Ore!");
        }
        break;
    }
    case DIAMOND_ORE: {
        if (!player.hasPermission("PluginName.diamond") && (!player.isOp())) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            player.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You do not have permission to mine Diamond Ore!");
        break;
    }
    }
    case EMERALD_ORE: {
        if (!player.hasPermission("PluginName.emerald") && (!player.isOp())) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            player.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You do not have permission to mine Emerald Ore!");
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting priority to Highest ot High, as Squiddie suggested, will make your event fire after the other plugin does. So you'll cancel the event before the other plugin has a chance to use the broken blocks for its action, ending in the action you want

Answer (score 0):

Set your event priority to `HIGH` or `HIGHEST` in order to have your code executed ***later*** chronologically. This gives you the "final say" in how the event is handled.

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.HIGH)
public void onPlayerBreakBlock(BlockBreakEvent e){
   ...
}
```

Don't automatically chose `HIGHEST` just because you can though. Generally prefer the least extreme priority that still accomplishes your goal. Then, if say, another plugin was conflicting with yours, they can make an even higher priority. See this link for more specific details: https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Event_API_Reference#Event_Priorities

Only use the `MONITOR` priority of you don't intend on changing the event at all. It is intended to indicate the final state of the event. Such as whether it was cancelled or not.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers and comments actually aren't correct, and I wanted to add a few more details and potentially offer some recommendations on how to clean up your code a tad.

When a block is broken, Bukkit will send the `BlockBreakEvent` to all registered listeners in the order of their priority. By default, the priority will always be `EventPriority.NORMAL`. The order in which listeners receive the event occurs in the following order:

1. `LOWEST`
2. `LOW`
3. `NORMAL`
4. `HIGH`
5. `HIGHEST`
6. `MONITOR`

The reason the `HIGHEST` priority is fired second-to-last is because it means "this event is the most important, and therefore gets the final say to manipulate the event."

In this case, you don't want to be the last plugin to process the event, you want to be the first. However, it is risky to set priorities to `LOWEST` or `HIGHEST` as there might be cases where other plugins need to handle information before or after you (WorldEdit for instance). Thus, you should set your event priority to `LOW`.

The last thing I want to mention is that you have a lot of duplicate code. This is not necessarily a problem when it comes to speed, but it does make things much harder to read. Below is a solution to both clean up your code and also fix the problems with event priority.

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.LOW)
public void onPlayerBreakBlock(BlockBreakEvent event) {
    List<Material> materialList = Arrays.asList(Material.COAL_ORE, Material.IRON_ORE, Material.GOLD_ORE, Material.DIAMOND_ORE, Material.EMERALD_ORE);
    Material type = event.getBlock().getType();
    Player player = event.getPlayer();

    if (materialList.contains(type) && !player.hasPermission("PluginName." + type.name().toLowerCase().replace("_ore", "")) && !player.isOp()) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You do not have permission to mine " + StringUtils.capitalizeFully(type.name()));
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I just want to add a little bit more clarification. There are a LOT of suggestions saying to set your priority to `HIGH` or `HIGHEST`, but the reason the player is being spammed is exactly because your event fires after the other event. That means even though you successfully cancel the event, it cancels all nine events and will spam the player's chat with 9 messages each time they try to break a block, rather than just 1 message.